# More efficient way to scrape ratings values from TripAdvisor using R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the ratings from TripAdvisor. So far, I have managed to extract the HTML nodes, turn them into character strings, extract the string that represents the numeric I need then converted it to the correct number, finally dividing it by 10 to get the correct value it is demonstrating.

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g1466790-d547811-Reviews-Royal_Botanic_Gardens_Kew-Kew_Richmond_upon_Thames_Greater_London_England.html"

ratings_too_big <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("#REVIEWS .ui_bubble_rating") %>%
  as.character() %>%
  substr(38,39) %>%
  as.numeric() 

ratings_too_big/10
```

This is without doubt very messy - what's a cleaner, more efficient way to do this? I have also tried Hadley Wickham's example shown [here](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/blob/master/demo/tripadvisor.R):

```
library(rvest)

url <- "http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g37209-d1762915-Reviews-JW_Marriott_Indianapolis-Indianapolis_Indiana.html"

reviews <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("#REVIEWS .innerBubble")

    rating <- reviews %>%
  html_node(".rating .rating_s_fill") %>%
  html_attr("alt") %>%
  gsub(" of 5 stars", "", .) %>%
  as.integer()
```

This was not successful, as no data was returned (there appears to be nothing in the HTML node ".rating .rating_s_fill"). I am new scraping and css identifiers, so apologies if the answer is obvious.

Comment: I should specify that I have requested permission from TripAdvisor regarding this project, so am not violating their terms of service.

Comment: What specifically do you think could be more efficient or less messy in your code?

Comment: Good question @DavidKlotz - this is my first foray into web scraping, so I feel that it's unlikely that this is the cleanest way to do it. I also wondered if there were other methods that utilised knowledge of HTML/CSS that I don't have. Basically, to all the developers out there that know more than me, how would you do it.

Comment: That link to Hadley's experiment was put up there 2 years ago. Most websites will have changed their coding over such an interval. The string " of 5 stars" appears nowhere in the source of the second URL, whereas in 2016 it use that string: I used the Chrome view-source:function on this link : https://web.archive.org/web/20160422224611/http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g37209-d1762915-Reviews-JW_Marriott_Indianapolis-Indianapolis_Indiana.html.